# Recursive nested sum

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I came across this function and I need to simplify it as much as possible, from a programming perspective, I can't afford $O(N)$ per sum.
$$G(N,D) = \sum_{i=1}^N F_i(D) $$ such that F is defined as follow :
$$
\begin{cases} 
F_i(X) = \sum_{j=1}^X F_{i-1}(j) & \text{if $i > 0$} \\ 
F_0(X) = 1 & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Dynamic programming and memoization could be useful here since it seems that many values will appear several times.

Comment: Unfortunately, N and D can be really big DP won't work for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i>0$ we have $F_i(X)=0$ if $X\le 0$, by induction is is easy to check that $F_i(1)=1$ for each $i\ge 0$, and $F_i(X)=F_{i-1}(X)+F_{i}(X-1)$ for all (integer) $X\ge 2$. This initial values and recurrence relation are counterparts of those from 
[Pascal’s triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Pascal%27s_triangle), which implies that $F_i(X)={i+X-1\choose i}$ for all integer $i\ge 0$ and $X\ge 1$. Then for $D\ge 1$,

$$G(N,D) = \sum_{i=1}^N F_i(D)= \sum_{i=1}^N {i+D-1\choose i}. $$

I guess that we can find an asymptotic evaluation of this sum. Also I recall that $G(D-1,D)={2D-2 \choose D-1}-1$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Sums_of_the_binomial_coefficients).